# Want to edit fields on the object review layout

Tags: workflow

We have a Salesforce object that we send to review by an admin. We have 88 custom fields for this object, but the layout for this review only shows a few fields. I can't figure out where in SF to edit this layout. I would like to add many fields to this layout, and also would like to remove the "Reject" button from the page.

[image: Here's what the page looks like]

Comment: It turns out this is a custom page that my compadre created in VisualForce. In general you can edit page layouts by the method describe below, which is why I accepted the answer. In my situation it turns out that I need to find the VF page and edit it, but I believe the accepted answer will be the most help to anybody searching in the future on this general issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Setup > Create > Objects > Lender

Scroll down a little bit and you will find your page layouts that you may then edit.

Make sure you have [these permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessing_layout_custom.htm) because otherwise you won't be able to do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Chance - I tried that but all I see is a single page layout there. If I create a new layout, how do I make the review layout use that one? Also, how do I determine what permissions I have? I'm beginning to suspect I don't have the right ones. But I am a System Administrator for our account

Comment: You would benefit greatly by taking a look at [the trailhead modules.](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en)

Try going through the admin beginner section. Specifically the "UI Customization"

Comment: The specific answer to your question would be to create a new page layout, add the fields you want/remove button, and then save that. You can then assign the page layout to profiles by going to setup > Create > Objects > Lender and scrolling down to the page layouts. There is a button named "Page Layout Assignment" where you can control who sees what layout.